# extract command from data.frame to create same df

Tags: r, dataframe

is there any package/command in R that reads a data.frame and then creates a command that can be used to create the exactly same data.frame without loading data, i.e., all data of the data.frame would have to be stored within the command?

e.g. if one has a data.frame like this:

```
mydata <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2),col2=c(3,4))
```

I just want to get the command such that reading "mydata" results in the command on the right hand side.

BR
Fabian

Comment: `dput(mydata)` maybe?

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `enquote`, which turns `mydata` back into an unevaluated `call`.  It can then be evaluated with `eval`.

```
> ( e <- enquote(mydata) )
# quote(list(col1 = c(1, 2), col2 = c(3, 4)))
> eval(e)
#   col1 col2
# 1    1    3
# 2    2    4
> identical(eval(e), mydata)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dput` function "Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection" and is as close to the right hand side as you would get. It actually contains more details about the structure of the object, as is seen below:

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(col1 = c(1, 2), col2 = c(3, 4)), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```